# Play-Scala: How to use method overloading In actions?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I want to make tow action with different Input and make one able to call the other:

```
def showQuestion(questionId :Long)=Action{
     Redirect(routes.Application.showQuestion(Question.find.byId(questionId)))
 }
 def showQuestion(question :Question)=Action{
    Ok(views.html.show(question))
 }
```

I tried the above but no luck. the compiler complaining:

```
found   : models.Question
[error]  required: Long
[error]      Redirect(routes.Application.showQuestion(Question.find.byId(questionId)))
```

referring to first one.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are missing something.

In your `routes` file, you can't map an Url to the second Action:

```
GET /question/:id    controllers.Question.showQuestion(id: Long)
GET /question/:question    controllers.Question.showQuestion(question: Question) // <== how to map the "question" in the Url ???
```

So why not something like that (in this case, it is not really relevant to use two methods) :

```
def showQuestion(questionId: Long)=Action{
     showQuestion(Question.find.byId(questionId))
}

private def showQuestion(question: Question)=Action{
    Ok(views.html.show(question))
}
```

Comment: actually I want the first route to be exist through the URL. I don't want the second to be exposed In the routes I just need It to be Available In the templates to save the process of passing the Id then fetch the Object from the database, so think private wont save me here.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a direct answer, however there's some point worth of thinking:

1. Main task for the router is *translation* and *type-validation* of  params from request to function's args, so it's definitely better use some common types such as `String`, `Int`, `Bool` etc, to identify the objects in DB instead trying to pass whole objects through the router. Actually your first route does that properly.
2. I can't find any good reason for using two separate actions for finding the object and rendering the template (with object found in other action). What's more, you are trying to do that by `Redirect`, so it creates **two** requests, it's redundant! You should just delete second route and use one action:

   ```
   GET /question/:id    controllers.Question.showQuestion(id: Long)

   def showQuestion(questionId: Long)=Action{
      Ok(views.html.show(Question.find.byId(questionId)))
   }
   ```
3. If you really, really want to split it to two separate functions, use sample of **@nico_ekito**, I think that you can delete second route in such case as well.
4. If in future you will want to overload function... better don't do it :) Overloading is fine, when you have static method available for usage in many places and it can differ with numer of arguments etc. Most probably it will be just more comfortable to work with different names of actions (even if routes will be similar) :

   ```
   GET  /question/:id     controllers.Question.showById(id: Long)
   GET  /question/:name   controllers.Question.showByName(name: String)

   // so finally in the view you can use it just as:
   <a href='@routes.Question.showById(item.id)' ...
   <a href='@routes.Question.showByName(item.name)' ...
   ```